# My WordPress site loading speed is very low

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I created a site with WordPress ( http://mashinmotor.com ). My site loading speed is very low so that the home page will take to load after about 1 minute. According to estimates in the gtmetrix problem, and I realized the size of site is 15Mb ,I fixed the problem and now the size of site is 1.5 Mb.

The next issue of the database queries that were sent, about 141 were sent request.WordPress plugin that uses this number to 53 requests done pretty well. But still did not change the site load time.

I have a search form with search and filter plugin. When I activated the form on the home page load time takes a minute and when I disabled the code that I wrote the site load time of 10 seconds.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyjKd.png)

My shortcode function code is:

```
    function headertab(){
    global $post; 
    $peyvandMain = get_field('homepagegallery');
    $showHeader = '';
    $showHeader .= '
    <div id="tab-container" class=" tab-container  ">

        <ul class=" etabs etabs_full">
        <div class="container">
        <li class="tab car-color"><a href="#tabs1-car"><img src="http://codebina.ir/work/mashinmotor/images/icon/car2.png"></a></li>
        <li class="tab motor-color"><a href="#tabs1-motor"><img src="http://codebina.ir/work/mashinmotor/images/icon/motor3.png"></a></li>
        <li class="tab truck-color"><a href="#tabs1-truck"><img src="http://codebina.ir/work/mashinmotor/images/icon/truck2.png"></a></li>
        </div>
        </ul>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="panel-container">

            <div calss="searchpanel" >
                <div class="searchMain">
                     ' . do_shortcode( '[searchandfilter id="2293"]' ) .'
                </div>
            </div>
                        <div class="peyvandMain">';
                if($peyvandMain):
                    foreach ($peyvandMain as $key) {
                        $showHeader .= '<a href="'. $key['description'] . '"><img src="'. $key['url'] . '" width="370px" height="65px"></a><br>';
                    }   
                endif;
                $showHeader .= '</div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

    </div>
    ';
    return $showHeader;
}
add_shortcode('headertab_main','headertab');
```

How can I fix this problem? Which one of a powerful plugin for making a search form that can be defined taxonomy and Post Type is better?